# Creating a half tone like pattern with cylinders using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a pattern consisting of different cylinders.

I definitely could create them row by row, but I am also planing to animate them - getting bigger and smaller and so on.
In the next step they should also react (collision).

Is it possible with Geonodes?

I tried but I had to make them real. (using 2.93 or will it be added in future maybe?)

I watched like "every" tutorial to get a clue how I could achieve it. found some but not on 2.93 or 2.92 and their nodes look way different, and every time I try some things it freezes Blender.

My workstation should be good enough, I think I just use them wrong.

I just duplicated these to get more rows, I need way more.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcwWGwyjko8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Byi7RVXyrnw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EboS5p8l7Z8

Comment: @Chris Not really humor. Dumped some links this morning, because I didn't have time to prepare a complete answer. OP can check them out in the mean time. I'm currently working on this effect.

Comment: Nice thanks a lot! i hadnt time to work on it again.. but i ll check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender 2.92.0. Let's start with a subdivided plane.

[image: Subdivided plane]

In edit mode select all faces then in top left corner click `Face`->`Poke Faces`

[image: Poked faces]

Then `Face`->`Tris to Quads`

[image]

I added a subdivided cube, because in my opinion it looked nicer than cylinders, and an empty to control the scale for animation purposes.

[image: Full setup]

And I did this node setup.

[image: Node setup]

From left:

1. `Attribute Fill` node sets `scale` on every instance (vertex) to 1.
2. `Attribute Vector Math` multiplies `position` of each instance by vector (1,0,0) and saves result to a custom `positionX` attribute, so `positionX` contains only (X,0,0) of each instance.
3. `Attribute Vector Math` calculates distance between `positionX` and (X,0,0) vector where X is X part of `Empty` location. Result of this operation is saved as custom attribute `distanceX`.
4. `Attribute Vector Math` divides scale of each instance (it's always set to 1 by `Attribute Fill` node above, but you can instead of it use `Attribute Randomize` to make initial scale of every instance a little different) by distanceX. This works fine for most cases, but when empty is really close to an instance we end up with extremely large scales (for example 1/0.001 = 1000)
5. `Attribute Math` is used to control how wide the "wave" of large instances there are. The larger the float value the smaller the "wave".
6. `Attribute Color Ramp` is placed to cut the scale so it never exceeds 1. It allows you also to control how small the far away instances should be. (just change color from black to dark gray)

And this is the final result.

[image: Final result]

You can animate the scales of the instanced objects by moving the empty so the animation is really easy.

[image: Moved empty]

Comment: crazy! thank you so much for your time!!!!!

Comment: thanks again! works rly nice. maybe u can give me a hint to a add more empties to animate like 2-3 waves?

Comment: Add two more points to the Color Ramp. Make them Black, White, Black, White. This should make more waves connected to same empty. For more complicated cases make a separate question.